# SQLite parameter substitution problem

Tags: python, sqlite

Using SQLite3 with Python 2.5, I'm trying to iterate through a list and pull the weight of an item from the database based on the item's name.

I tried using the "?" parameter substitution suggested to prevent SQL injections but it doesn't work. For example, when I use:

```
for item in self.inventory_names:
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ?", item)
    self.cursor.close()
```

I get the error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.

I believe this is somehow caused by the initial creation of the database; the module I made that actually creates the DB does have 8 bindings.

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Equipment 
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT,
    price INTEGER, 
    weight REAL, 
    info TEXT, 
    ammo_cap INTEGER, 
    availability_west TEXT,
    availability_east TEXT)""")
```

However, when I use the less-secure "%s" substitution for each item name, it works just fine. Like so:

```
for item in self.inventory_names:
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = '%s'" % item)
    self.cursor.close()
```

I can't figure out why it thinks I have 8 bindins when I'm only calling one. How can I fix it?

Comment: The number of columns is not the number of bindings.  The number of "?"'s in the query is the number of bindings.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just figured the code was somehow trying to use the bindings referenced by the "create table" statement. I didn't realize it referred to the number of letters in the item itself.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The `Cursor.execute()` method expects a sequence as second parameter. You are supplying a string which happens to be 8 characters long.

Use the following form instead:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ?", [item])
```

Python library reference: sqlite3 [Cursor Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

Answer (score 83):

I have spent half a day trying to figure out why something like this would give me an error:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from ? WHERE name = ?", (table_name, name))
```

only to find out that table names *cannot be parametrized*. Hope this will help other people save some time.

Comment: You can do something like: `cursor.execute("SELECT * from %s WHERE name = ?" % table_name, (name,))`, although that may make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: For situations where user input determines the table, I pull the name of the table out of a dict and raise an exception if the contents of the input are unexpected. Probably not the _best_ way to go about it, but seems less liable to result in SQL injection.

Comment: @James I'm curious, in what situations have you needed to change which table you're inserting into based on user input? Using a dict sounds like a pretty good idea for that situation, I use them whenever I would have used a switch statement.

Comment: @num1: anytime you want to have a generic class that takes a table name as a class init() parameter.  Thus, you do not want to hard-code the table name but have it be a variable...

Comment: You use `[]` for table, field names and `?` for values,

Comment: Came here searching how to pass multiple arguments go SQLite query =)

Comment: Is this a limitation of SQL, SQLite, or the Python DB-API?

Comment: @memilanuk The reason must be "hidden" somewhere in the module or [cursor source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L630) (origin name appears to be "pysqlite") (and not the [library wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/sqlite3)) since I could not find anything in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or PEP 249 ("DB-API 2.0") [.execute()](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id15) or [#paramstyle](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Comment: Digging further (_pysqlite_query_execute -> bind_parameters -> bind_param ) leads to the SQLITE C Interface Docs on [Binding Values To Prepared Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) and [Parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). But I still don't see anything on why it cannot be used for the table name...

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019599/sqlite-why-cant-parameters-be-used-to-set-an-identifier

Answer (score 34):

The argument of `cursor.execute` that represents the values you need inserted in the database should be a tuple (sequence). However consider this example and see what's happening:

```
>>> ('jason')
'jason'

>>> ('jason',)
('jason',)
```

The first example evaluates to a string instead; so the correct way of representing single valued tuple is as in the second evaluation. Anyhow, the code below to fix your error.

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ?", (item,))
```

Also giving the `cursor.execute` value arguments as strings,(which is what you are doing) results in the first evaluation in the example and results into the error you are getting.

Comment: @Kirk but parameter substitution doesn't work for sqlite table names, so the one above is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for point this out. I know it's a rookie mistake, but single item tuples still trip me up when I haven't written Python in a while...

Answer (score 15):

The [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module supports *two* kinds of placeholders for parameters:

## qmark style

Use one or more `?` to mark the position of each parameter, and supply a list or tuple of parameters. E.g.:

```
curs.execute(
    "SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ? AND price = ?",
    ["lead", 24],
)
```

## named style

Use `:par` placeholders for each named parameter, and supply a dict. E.g.:

```
curs.execute(
    "SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = :name AND price = :price",
    {"name": "lead", "price": 24},
)
```

Advantages of named style parameters is that you don't need to worry about the order of parameters, and each `:par` can be used multiple times in large/complex SQL queries.

Comment: How about different paramstyle options? And which one sqlite3 supports and where this has been written? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Answer (score 2):

have You tried this ? :

```
for item in self.inventory_names:
    t = (item,)
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ?", t)
    self.cursor.close()
```

cursor.execute() expects a sequence (list,tuple) as second parameter. (-> ddaa )

Answer (score 2):

## A list of different parameter styles for sqlite3

A bit late to answer it but, as [Vladimir Ignatyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882187/vladimir-ignatyev) stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem/51570095#comment107548484_51570095) comment, the official documentation has the parameter styles [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

Here are the formats from that post:

| paramstyle | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| qmark | Question mark style, e.g. `WHERE name=?` |
| numeric | Numeric, positional style, e.g. `WHERE name=:1` |
| named | Named style, e.g. `WHERE name=:name` |
| format | ANSI C printf format codes, e.g. `WHERE name=%s` |
| pyformat | Python extended format codes, e.g. `WHERE name=%(name)s` |

Answer (score 1):

Quoting (is that what the parens mean?) the ? with parens seems to work for me. I kept trying with (literally) '?' but I kept getting

> ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

When I did:

> SELECT fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE (?)

instead of:

> SELECT fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE '?'

It worked.

Is this some python 2.6 thing?

Comment: If you're using sqlite3's parameter substitution (instead of Python's %s string interpolation), then the ? should not the be quoted at all, i.e. `SELECT fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE ?`. It just happens adding brackets in the SQL does not change the meaning, so `SELECT fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE (?)` is equivalent to without the ().

Comment: If you're using Django and your query is `SELECT fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE "%s"` then you will also want to avoid the quotation marks too. `cursor.execute()` will not recognize %s as a binding in that query. So use `cursor.execute("Select fact FROM factoids WHERE key LIKE %s", (key_name, ))`

Answer (score 0):

each element of items has to be a tuple.
assuming names looks something like this:

```
names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mary']
```

you should do the following:

```
for item in self.inventory_names:
self.cursor.execute("SELECT weight FROM Equipment WHERE name = ?", (item, ))
```

by using (item, ) you are making it a tuple instead of a string.

Comment: This'll generate a lot of queries. N+1 problem.

Comment: I somehow have a full edit queue, so i leave a comment for an edit. --- cursor.execute function accepts 3 parameters: query string, iterable item list, a switch. here item list for a single item can be made either using "[item]" or "(item,)" --- the answer accepted is just another form of solution, and this is the other @proofit404

Answer (score -7):

Try

```
execute("select fact from factoids where key like ?", "%%s%" % val)
```

You don't wrap anything around the `?` at all, Python sqlite will correctly convert it into a quoted entity.