# Python 2.7 problems with sqlite3.Cursor.execute function

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a really frustrating problem

I have a function that accepts a cursor to a sqlite3.Connection object and then modifies the database

my code is something like this:

```
#DOES NOT WORK
def update(dbc, tableName, value, value2):
    dbc.execute("update ? set MyValue = ? where Something = ?;",\
    [tableName, value, value2])

#WORKS
def update2(dbc, tableName value, value2):
    dbc.execute("update {0} set MyValue = {1} where Something = {2};".format(
    tableName, value, value2))

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("begin;")
update(c,"Something","Something Else") #FAILS
update2(c,"Something","Something Else") #OK
```

I get the error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

I have tried commenting out the first execute("begin;") statement because I don't really understand it but I know that it speeds up my code dramatically in other parts instead of having to commit every single input.  Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, I guess it doesn't work for table names, bleh.  Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem

Comment: I see you are new here. Welcome. You can answer your own question, don't leave it unanswered.

Comment: Cant for another 7 hours.  Will do it tomorrow I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures that after hours of searching I find the answer in the next 10 minutes.  Table names cannot be loaded in this way...  Seems silly.  Here is a link to the original answer:  [SQLite parameter substitution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem)