# Python SQLite3: Cannot Create Table with Variable in Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have the following code to create a table if it does not already exist in a database.

```
TABLE_NAME = 'Test'

sql = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE.db')
cur = sql.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id TEXT)', [TABLE_NAME])
sql.commit()
```

But I keep getting `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

I have other code such as `cur.execute('INSERT * INTO database VALUES(?,?)', [var1, var2])` that works fine.

Comment: [table names cannot be parameterized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597198/5323213). you can use python string formatting to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, parameters cannot be used to substitute for database identifiers, only for values.  You will have to build the SQL command, with the table name specified, as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates the table

```
import sqlite3
sql = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE.db')
cur = sql.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (id TEXT)')
sql.commit()
```

Comment: I know how to create a table. My problem is I wanted to create a table based on a variable using ? but that is apparently not possible

Comment: My bad. Yes, as stated above - parametrized queries are for DML but not for DDL queries.