# SQLite3 in Python - unrecognised token

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been working on some controlled assessment for my GCSE computer science and I have come across a bit of a problem. I need to be able to create different tables, if not already created, and I need to name them according to what class the person is in (which I would not know). I get the user to input their class and then save it in a list (nameyear) at index[1].

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (Name text, Score integer)''' % nameyear[1])
```

The class is saved in this sort of format, '11x1'. It does not allow me to use '11x1' as the name of the table despite it being saved as a string. How would I overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite parameter substitution problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem): check out ddaa answer specifically.

Comment: _"I need to be able to create different tables"_ Why? Why not use a column for whatever information you were going to store in the table name? Making lots of tables like this is usually bad, which is why most databases don't let you use query parameters for table/column names.

Comment: I agree with @ColonelThirtyTwo, aim for normalization. Store all in one table with identifying column. Additionally, you don't want table names to be dynamic and open-ended impacting maintainbility. Store class names as a field.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I had originally tried doing this, however, I have looked over the mark scheme for the assessment and it says that the classes must be kept seperate so i decided to make one database but different tables. I have since tried changing the code to:                                       c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (Name text, Score integer)''' % str(nameyear[1])) which now just gives the error message of the variable being an unidentified token

Answer (score 0):

maybe nameyear[1] is not a string so juste cast it like that :

```
str(nameyear[1])
```