# Sqlite inserting values into table with for loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making a voting system and set it up so that the user can put all candidates for a position in Tkinter Entry at once separated by commas and press a button to have a new vote created for that position with those candidates.

Below is the code I believe relevant.

```
# positions drop down
        newVoteChoosePositionLabel = Label(admin, text="Choose the position you are voting for", font=("Arial", 12))
        newVoteChoosePositionLabel.place(x=265, y=170)
        position = StringVar(admin)
        position.set("Chief")
        newVoteOption = OptionMenu(admin, position, "Chief", "First Lieutenant", "Second Lieutenant", "Third Lieutenant",
                                   "Fourth Lieutenant")
        newVoteOption.place(x=355, y=195)

        #add candidates
        addCandLabel = Label(admin, text="Add candidates below, separate each candidate with a comma then press enter when all candidates have been entered"
                             , font=("Arial", 11), wraplength=300, anchor=W)
        addCandLabel.place(x=255, y=235)
        addCandEntry = Entry(admin, width=40)
        addCandEntry.place(x=272, y=295)

        #new vote
        newVoteButton = Button(admin, text="Create Vote", width=15)
        newVoteButton.place(x=335, y=325)

        def newVote(event):
            pos = position.get()
            candidates = addCandEntry.get()
            formatted = [x.strip() for x in candidates.split(',')]
            for x in formatted:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)", pos,x,0)


        addCandEntry.bind("<Return>", newVote)
        newVoteButton.bind("<Button-1>", newVote)
```

I will put the full code at the bottom of this post.

The problem I have been having is that whenever I click the button I get an error saying `TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (x given)` where `x` is the amount of times the for loop ran.
I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening because the for loop should be inserting the three supplied values to the sqlite table each time it runs, so I'm not sure why it is causing an error based on how often the for loop runs.

Below is the full code I have. Careful it's messy

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import datetime


# testing purposes only
password = 'test'

# create database file
conn = sqlite3.connect('firefight')
c = conn.cursor()

# create tables
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
          username text, password text, admin boolean)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS positions(
          position text)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS current(
          position text, candidate text, votes int)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS past(
          date DATE, position text, candidate text, votes int, winner boolean)''')

c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES('admin', 'VoteProgram', 'yes')")


'''
tables:
users:
    username text
    password text
    admin boolean
positions:
    position text
current:
    position text
    candidate text
    votes int
past:
    position text
    candidate text
    votes int
    winner boolean
'''

# define root window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)

# Admin sign in Label
areAdmin = Label(root, text="Administrator sign in", font=("Arial", 18))
areAdmin.pack()

# password label and password
passwordLabel = Label(root, text="Password: ", font=("Arial", 12))
passwordLabel.place(x=300, y=30)

# password entry
adminPasswordEntry = Entry(root)
adminPasswordEntry.place(x=385, y=32.5)

# function for button
def getEnteredPassword(event):
    enteredPassword = adminPasswordEntry.get()
    if enteredPassword == password:
        # define admin window
        admin = tkinter.Toplevel()
        admin.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
        admin.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)
        # label saying to change password
        changePasswordLabel = Label(admin, text="It is recommended to change your password the first time you log in.",
                                    font=("Arial", 16), wraplength=500)
        changePasswordLabel.pack()
        # old password
        changePassword_OldPasswordLabel = Label(admin, text="Old Password: ", font=("Arial", 12))
        changePassword_OldPasswordLabel.place(x=250, y=50)
        changePassword_OldPassword = Entry(admin)
        changePassword_OldPassword.place(x=365, y=52.5)
        # new password
        changePassword_NewPasswordLabel = Label(admin, text="New Password: ", font=("Arial", 12))
        changePassword_NewPasswordLabel.place(x=250, y=70)
        changePassword_NewPassword = Entry(admin)
        changePassword_NewPassword.place(x=365, y=72.5)

        # function to change password
        def passwordChangeCommand(event):
            global password
            oldPasswordValue = changePassword_OldPassword.get()
            newPasswordValue = changePassword_NewPassword.get()
            if oldPasswordValue == password:
                password = newPasswordValue
            else:
                wrong = tkinter.Toplevel()
                wrong.minsize(width=200, height = 100)
                wrong.maxsize(width=200, height = 100)
                Label(wrong, text="Sorry that password is incorrect!", font=("Arial", 24), anchor=W, wraplength=180,
                      fg="red").pack()

        # submit button
        newPasswordSubmit = Button(admin, text="Submit", width=10, command=passwordChangeCommand)
        newPasswordSubmit.place(x=350, y=100)

        newVoteLabel = Label(admin, text="Create New Vote", font=("Arial", 16))
        newVoteLabel.place(x=310, y=135)

        # positions drop down
        newVoteChoosePositionLabel = Label(admin, text="Choose the position you are voting for", font=("Arial", 12))
        newVoteChoosePositionLabel.place(x=265, y=170)
        position = StringVar(admin)
        position.set("Chief")
        newVoteOption = OptionMenu(admin, position, "Chief", "First Lieutenant", "Second Lieutenant", "Third Lieutenant",
                                   "Fourth Lieutenant")
        newVoteOption.place(x=355, y=195)

        #add candidates
        addCandLabel = Label(admin, text="Add candidates below, separate each candidate with a comma then press enter when all candidates have been entered"
                             , font=("Arial", 11), wraplength=300, anchor=W)
        addCandLabel.place(x=255, y=235)
        addCandEntry = Entry(admin, width=40)
        addCandEntry.place(x=272, y=295)

        #new vote
        newVoteButton = Button(admin, text="Create Vote", width=15)
        newVoteButton.place(x=335, y=325)

        def newVote(event):
            pos = position.get()
            candidates = addCandEntry.get()
            formatted = [x.strip() for x in candidates.split(',')]
            for x in formatted:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)", pos,x,0)


        addCandEntry.bind("<Return>", newVote)
        newVoteButton.bind("<Button-1>", newVote)

    else:
        wrong = tkinter.Toplevel()
        wrong.minsize(width=200, height=100)
        wrong.maxsize(width=200, height=100)
        Label(wrong, text="Sorry that password is incorrect!", font=("Arial", 24), anchor=W, wraplength=180,
              fg="red").pack()

# enter button for password
passwordEnterButton = Button(root, text="Enter", width=10)
passwordEnterButton.place(x=360, y=60)
passwordEnterButton.bind("<Button-1>", getEnteredPassword)
root.bind("<Return>", getEnteredPassword)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You have defined the `admin` column in the `users` table as `boolean`, yet you are inserting the text `yes`.  Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: No but that code is currently not in use and isn't what is giving the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite parameter substitution problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem)

Comment: @robyschek that did not answer my question

Comment: @Shniper `execute` expects params to be in a tuple: `c.execute("INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)", (pos,x,0))`. The error has nothing with the loop.