# Data Base Query Using Tkinter OptionMenu Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to learn how I can query my database using the MenuOption selection.
When a user clicks the MenuOption button it displays the multiple options properly but I am not sure how to get it to query database for the option selected which is named the same as the database tables.

I have tried a number of different ways using the online information I have been reading but nothing seems to work yet.

I have to be missing something in a variable method to call the option name which is a table in the database.

Once it will pull the data from the table selected I'll need to populate a widget with the data, I assume a ComboBox is best suited for that?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
def window_2():
    window_2 = tkinter.Tk()
    image2 = 'window2.gif'
    bg_image2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=image2)
    w = 1024
    h = 612
    ws = window_2.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = window_2.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    window_2.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    panel2 =tkinter.Label(window_2, image=bg_image2)
    panel2.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
    panel2.image = bg_image2
    window_2.title('Recipes')
    window_2.wm_iconbitmap('recipe.ico')

    def select():
    # optional
        selection = var.get()
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM Appetizers') # THIS ONLY PRINT THAT TABLE "Appetizer" BECAUSE IT IS NAMED, I NEED TO REPLACE THAT WITH THE VARIABLE FOR THE SELECTION.
        data = c.fetchall()
        print(data)

    var = tkinter.StringVar(window_2)
    var.set('Menu')

    choices = [
        'Appetizers',
        'Beef',
        'Bread',
        'Cake',
        'Chicken',
        'Chilli',
        'Curry',
        'Desert',
        'Drinks',
        'Egg',
        'Fish',
        'Pasta',
        'Pork',
        'Potato',
        'Rice',
        'Salad',
        'Sandwich',
        'Sauce',
        'Sea Food',
        'Slow Cooker',
        'Soup',
        'Stew',
        'Tofu',
        'Vegetables']

    option = tkinter.OptionMenu(window_2, var, *choices)
    option.place(x=215, y=120)

    button = tkinter.Button(window_2, text="check value selected", command=select)
    button.pack
    button.place(x=370, y=120)
```

Comment: Try `c.execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(selection))`.

Comment: That did the trick perfectly... I greatly appreciate the help!. Can I ask the significance or meaning of the { } brackets for future reference?

Comment: @DT2000: Read [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings). Relevant [sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem)

Comment: Thank you once again... it is much appreciated.