# How to select from SQLite table if table is variable (python)

Tags: python, sqlite, variables, tkinter

I am trying to select from a SQLite table but I want to use a variable instead of a specifying a table name. I am writing a class that accesses a different table depending on the keyword entered on a previous tkinter toplevel. I have brought the keyword into the class but I can't use self.keyword or the usual ('SELECT blah blah FROM ?', (self.keyword,)). I've searched online and have been unable to find anything. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you'll have to use plain string substitution, i.e. `"select blah blah from %s" % name_of_table`

Comment: what is the error you get?  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228912/sqlite-parameter-substitution-problem

Comment: You cannot use placeholders on table and column names.

Comment: @acw1668: that suggestion isn't for using a placeholder, it's for using string formatting.

Comment: @Bryan My comment is on OP which used placeholder on table name.

Comment: acw1668 is right. But I didn't know I could use plain python string substitution when writing in SQLite so it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python supports various methods for substituting variables in strings,

*substitution where order matters*

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT blah blah FROM ? WHERE name = ?",
             ['MYTABLE', 'salik'])
```

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT blah blah FROM {} WHERE name = {}".format("MYTABLE","salik"))
```

*substitution where order does not matter*

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT blah blah FROM :table_name WHERE name = :name",
             {name: 'salik', table_name: 'MYTABLE'})
```

Use any of the method mentioned above
I personally would recommend you to learn formatting strings using format method

Comment: .format also allows you to change digits after decimal point