# How to call the variable from text into sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a GUI in PyQt5 and I want to delete the data inside my sqlite3 using PyQt5 but I can't call the variable from Pyqt5 using sqlite3, I want to call the variable remove from sqlite3 look at the second picture but it didn't work the error is in the last picture is there someone knows how to do it in sqlite3?

[image: image 1]

[[image: image 22]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and always avoid using images for code.

Comment: dont even think about writing SQL by concatenating strings of user inputs.  makes you look real 1990s security wise and fail any job interview.  https://xkcd.com/327/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection  use parametrized queries.

Comment: this Gui is for only my friend who had a store and there is no big issue in security threat because it is just obly a record of his product.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating this by hand (see my remark about sql injection) and executing
`delete from Product where product_name = product` rather than `delete from Product where product_name = 'product'`.  there is no `product` column.

the problem has nothing to do with pyqt or Python, just bad sql usage.  Your code wouldn't work on sql command line either.  Not a big issue when you are learning this for the first time, we've all been there.  But really a no no going forward.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/228981 they talk about bind/parametrized query parameters for sqlite.  Should fix your problem.

Comment: I am new to sqlite3 and I don't know much about it, I read about parameterized query bit I'm confuse about it on how to use it with PyQt5 to call the variable inside PyQt5 using sqlite3. Do you have any sample on how to do it in pyqt5 and sqlite3?

Comment: By the way, thank you for the link it might help me knowing about sqlite3

Comment: @liendelguibingcan  my suggestion is the opposite.  Tricky piece of code?  Try it out on its own, in a script on in the REPL.  get it working and only then put it into your webapp/mobile app/pyqt5.  Anyway, db code needs the db **and** the table so hard for someone to demo for you.  Just remember: sqllite has 1 bind syntax.  Mysql will have a slightly different one.  Principle is the same tho.